# How do I in an Android Imageview, replace one colour with another (black to white) in the xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

How do I in an Android `Imageview`, replace one colour with another (**black to white**) in the `xml`?

I've placed 3 images in a horizontal `linearlayout`, each image has a transparent background, but is mainly the colour black. I'd like to replace the colour of each of these images to white from within the Android xml.

I don't know how to do this, how would you suggest to accomplish this?

My code so far is below:

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="230dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_se"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/search"
                        android:backgroundTint=""/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_hea"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/heart"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_menu"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />



                    </LinearLayout>
```

My icons:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about changing the source (android:src) of the ImageView to white, right? Not the background color? If so, you can't do this in xml, you'll have to change the color programatically.

```
ImageView seImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_se);
ImageView heaImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_hea);
ImageView menuImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_menu);

seImageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
heaImageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
menuImageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: So far when I attempt to do this. The whole Imageview gets replaced by the colour white ("#ffffff") not just the icon

Comment: Shouldn't be. Is your icon a solid black png with transparency? Can you post the image?

Comment: For kicks, I took your icons and placed them into one of my own projects and applied color filters to them. The result is exactly as expected. The only thing I can still suggest is to look at your code and check that you're also not setting a background color somewhere to your ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert your drawable to white or any other color and apply that drawable to your image view,

```
public static Drawable convertColorDrawable(int resource, int color, Context context) {
        final Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resource);

        drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        return drawable.mutate();
}
```

Example:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_se);

seImageView.setImageDrawable(convertColorDrawable(R.drawable.search, android.R.color.white, context));
```